# Correct syntax for manually scaling the width of lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot a melted dataframe using the following code (just a minimal fragment shown for clarity):

```
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = Date, y= value)) +
          geom_line(aes(color = Variable, size = Variable)) +
          scale_color_manual(values = c("dark green", "azure3", "goldenrod4")) +
          scale_size_manual(values = c(.6, .8, .6)) +
          .
          .
          .
```

but get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

But if I change `size = Variable` to `linewidth = Variable`, I get a different warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: Using linewidth for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

If I further change  `scale_size_manual` to  `scale_linewidth_manual`, I get an error message:

```
Error in scale_linewidth_manual(values = c(0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.3)) : 
  could not find function "scale_linewidth_manual"
```

What is the correct syntax here? Unfortunately, ggplot2's help got me nowhere, so I would be very appreciative for some guidance.

Comment: Two of these are warnings, not errors, and should have still produced output. Did your first code block give you the result you wanted? If not, what was wrong with it?

Comment: They did produce output, but i want to ensure that my code does not produce errors or warnings. There's a ggplot2 blog at https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/08/ggplot2-3-4-0-size-to-linewidth/ that addresses the change from size to linewidth. but the ggplot reference manual at  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf does not mention anything about scale_linewidth_manual. I expected that the word "Size" would be repaced by linewidth, but this ws not the case.

Answer (score 9):

### Edit

Since ggplot2 3.4.1, `scale_linewidth_manual()` (and the identity variant) exists.

### Original answer

The current preferred option seems to be to use `scale_discrete_manual()`, see also https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5050. To demonstrate:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics_long, aes(date, value01)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(colour = variable, linewidth = variable)
  ) +
  scale_discrete_manual("linewidth", values = seq(0.1, 3, length.out = 5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! My searching did not turn up  this link and it solves the problem completely. Thank you very much.

Comment: One remaining question is whether the non-existence of `scale_linewidth_manual` is a bug?

Comment: No it is not a bug. It is either a missing feature, or this is by design. As the issue is still open, you can weigh in if you think that the scale should be included at some point.